# Google python api how to define the service instance

Tags: python, google-python-api

In the Google API for python to send an email, https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending you can find this method

```
def send_message(service, user_id, message):

  try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message)
               .execute())
    print 'Message Id: %s' % message['id']
    return message
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % error
```

I am following that tutorial, and I have already followed another tutorial for getting the authentication, but my question is what to pass for this **service** variable. how to define it?

That page says nothing about it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excerpt from a [Quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) provided by Google.

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

    Creates a Gmail API service object.
    """
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```

In their example they generate the OAuth credentials using a client secret JSON file generated by their application. How you generate those credentials really depends on how you want your application to work.